# Return Sorted Dictionary after sorting of dictionary

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

In dictionary we have multiple key value pairs. We sorted these, and return type is [(key:value)] pair. But we need the same return time in sorted order. Please give solution for that.

Comment: A dictionary has no "sorted order". It has no order. What does your question even mean? Show input and desired output, please. (In particular, illustrate the opaque concept "the same return time in sorted order".)

Comment: relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys

Answer (score 2):

A Dictionary has no order in Swift, so the notion "sorted dictionary" is meaningless. LiteralDictionary maintains sort order at the expense of slow key lookup, but it can be created only from a literal — not by sorting an existing dictionary. You could create your own ordered dictionary implementation, but it would be a lot of work, and again would almost certainly be at the expense of key lookup speed. You might look at [Ordered dictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969688/ordered-dictionary-in-swift) and similar, but would do better to ask yourself why you want this at all; you have a sorted array of key–value pairs, so just use that and stop.