# iOS - Order in dictionary issue

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from sorted array of times (which are string). 
Here is the code:

```
  var usernameCommentsSorted: [String : [String : String]] = [:]
  print("not sorted: \(Array(usernameComments.keys))")
  let sortedKeys = Array(usernameComments.keys).sorted()
  print("sorted: \(sortedKeys)")

  for time in sortedKeys {

    print("time in for loop -- \(time) --")
    usernameCommentsSorted[time] = ["F" : "F"]

  }

  print("sorted final dictionary: \(usernameCommentsSorted)")
```

and here's the output:

[image]

So my question is, why is the dictionary not receiving the times as the for in loop goes? Maybe I'm missing some behaviour of dictionaries.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to sort dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted. If order is important to you, use an array.

Comment: @CodeDifferent is right. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30969688/3171675

Answer (score 0):

`Array` has value sematics in Swift.  When you call `Array(usernameComments.keys)` it creates a copy of the dictionary keys.  When you call `.sorted` you are calling the version that creates a copy (`.sort` does an inplace sort).  In any case you cannot mutate the keys array of a dictionary.  You can, however keep a separate sorted copy of the array, which you need to update any time the dictionary is modified. Then you can iterate throught he dictionary in sorted order like:

```
for key in sortedKeys {
   print(dictionary[key]!)
}
```

Apple does have an objective C class that is an ordered hashtable.  Consider whether or not [NSMutableOrdered](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableorderedset) set is a better data structure choice for your use case.  As the name implies it has unique keys that you can order.