# Changing tuples to dictionary messes the order

Tags: swift

I want to convert tuples(in my case `(key:String, value:EquipmentData)`) to `[String:Equipment]` in the alphabetical order of the key

```
let sortedEquipmentData = typeData.sorted() { $0.0 < $1.0 }
let dictionary = [String:EquipmentData](uniqueKeysWithValues: sortedEquipmentData)
```

`typeData` is `[String:EquipmentData]`

`sortedEquipmentData` is correctly ordered but,
`dictionary` return a messed up version of `sortedEquipmentData`

Comment: Dictionaries have no order so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Dictionaries do not maintain order. It's their nature.

Comment: And if you'd like a source: "A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a _collection with no defined ordering_." https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html For ordering, you need an array.

Comment: You could do `var myDictionary: [Int: [String: EquipmentData]]?`: [Ordered map in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969688/ordered-map-in-swift)

Comment: As stated in some of the comments a dictionary will not maintain order.  You can still access the data as though it was sorted though.  

Convert all of your data to a dictionary as you have done, but also maintain a sorted array of the dictionary keys.  When doing any operations you can use this array and then use the key from there to pull the data from the dictionary.